# Double Headers in CGridView in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

Lets suppose i have the following CGridView.. This is just example Cgridview..

[image]

but instead of this, i want to make my CgridView in yii 1.1 like this..

[image]

This is what i have done in tables.. but i want to do this in CgridView in Yii.. I have searched on SOF, but unable to find... Is it possible to do like this?

Comment: Hope this would be helpful http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/528/insert-a-multirow-header-in-cgridview/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii create multiple row header and merge it with other columns in GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317593/yii-create-multiple-row-header-and-merge-it-with-other-columns-in-gridview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to user multiheader, you can use GroupGridView instead of CGridView. See: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/groupgridview/